# How to move section,subsection, etc. title entirely to page margin?

Tags: sectioning, margins

How to move section's, subsection's, etc. titles entirely to page margin?
I want to have section's titles at margin and section text should start at the same height as section title. I'm working with `article.cls`.

I'm trying to obtain the following effect:

```
1.1 Section title  Section text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
                   amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
                   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
                   ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
                   fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
                   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
```

Comment: What is meant to happen if the title is wider than the margin? Take a look at `memoir` (`> texdoc memoir`)  section 6.6 *Lower level headings* for an example of how to do this with `\paragraph` sectional headings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In such case I will be satisfied when title simple break into few lines.

Comment: Have a look at `titlesec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Javier Bezos' comment and [`titlesec` docs](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) I made the solution to my problem, this is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[preview,border={10pc 2pc 10pc 2pc}]{standalone}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

 \titleformat{name=\section,page=even}[leftmargin]
 {\normalfont
 \bfseries\filleft}
 {\thesection}{.5em}{}

 \titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}[rightmargin]
 {\normalfont
 \bfseries\filright}
 {\thesection}{.5em}{}

 \titlespacing{\section}
 {8pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

 \begin{document}

 \section{Section title}
 \blindtext
 \section{Very very long section title}
 \blindtext[2]

 \end{document}
```

... and this is the result:

[image: MWE result]

I hope someone will take advantage from my question and answer in the future. I really appreciate the comments bellow the stated question.

Comment: Could you post a minimal working code so we can produce a screen shot of it and see the output?

Comment: @Sigur, done :)